# purpose of "just me" and "everyone" radio button

Tags: installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why install for “just me” as opposed to “everybody”? (windows installer)](https://superuser.com/questions/107930/why-install-for-just-me-as-opposed-to-everybody-windows-installer)

when i was installing a installer it had two radio buttons "just me"  and "everyone"

i am not able to differentiate these two radio buttons.

can any one guide me in this?

Comment: @subash - Hello, welcome to Super User. Your question has been migrated here, where it is more adapted. To regain ownership over your question, you should create an account here, and associate it with your Stack Overflow account in user options.

Comment: Besides, this question has a duplicate with complete answers on Stack Overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/349694/why-install-for-just-me-as-opposed-to-everybody-windows-installer I flagged it to be migrated here, so we can close this one as duplicate of the more complete one.

Answer (score 4):

Just me will install only to your profile (desktop/application menu).

Everyone will install into the shared profile *(All Users)* that every user has access to.

Answer (score 0):

Its to do with user accounts - Just me would make the application only available to the current user.

Everyone would be to anyone who logs into the PC.